# TFS2015 Release management - Deploying tasks in parallel - system error 67

Tags: tfs-2015, release-management

My team has been encountering this particular error randomly and intermittently.
We will deploy an application using TFS Release management to 160-170 servers, and if we have our "Windows Copy Files" and "Powershell on Target machines" steps set to deploy in parallel we get:

System error 67 has occured.
The network name cannont be found.

When our tasks are set to NOT deploy in parallel, the error seems to resolve itself. We would like to know the root cause of this error, so that we can deploy successfully and promptly. Has anyone else encountered and resolved this error? MSFT doesn't seem to have an answer for this.

Comment: Sounds like a network glitch, is there a way to control the number of parallel activities?

Comment: Unfortunately not, it is either parallel or not. Found this article: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/875441/you-may-receive-a-the-network-name-cannot-be-found-error-message-when-you-use-the-fully-qualified-domain-name-to-connect-to-a-remote-computer-from-a-windows-server-2003-based,-windows-xp-based-or-windows-2000-based-computer which may be our root cause. It is outdated but I'm guessing still applies, going to try workaround 1

Comment: Could you give a test with deploy to  20~30 servers in parallel  one time? If it works which means the issue may not related to TFS release management itself. It's related your company's server or network environment.

Comment: Yes, we ran parallel deployments of 40 servers at a time with no problem. Increasing the DNS timeout on our tfs server didn't seem to resolve the error. We see poor performance across our network including slower user response times, and increased sql write times. We need to be able to deploy to more than 40 servers at a time thought, any ideas of what to look at in our network or on our server?